# How to fetch fetch data in background thread in MagicalRecord

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

For normal instance I am fetching the data from my table `Folders` like this one

```
+ (void)getCurrentFolderFileForParentFolderID:(NSString *)parentFolderID sortBy:(NSString *)sortBy asending:(BOOL)asending withCompletionHandler:(void(^)(id response,NSError *error))completionHandler {
NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"parentfolderidlocal = %@", parentFolderID];
NSArray *folders = [Folders MR_findAllSortedBy:sortBy ascending:asending withPredicate:filter];
NSArray *files = [Files MR_findAllSortedBy:sortBy ascending:asending withPredicate:filter];
completionHandler(@{@"folders":folders,@"files":files},nil);
}
```

It is working superfine without any issue, but whenever I am trying to fetch the data from background I am having some strange issue, I have tried the following ways to fetch the data in background queue getting same issue all the time

**Process One:**
Calling it in a dispatch queue

```
dispatch_async(fileSystemBackGroundQueue(), ^{
    [DataBaseManager getCurrentFolderFileForParentFolderID:parentFolderID sortBy:sortBy asending:asending withCompletionHandler:^(id response, NSError *error) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
                completionHandler(response, error);
            });
    }];
});
```

where `fileSystemBackGroundQueue()` is as follow

```
dispatch_queue_t fileSystemBackGroundQueue() {
static dispatch_once_t queueCreationGuard;
static dispatch_queue_t queue;
dispatch_once(&queueCreationGuard, ^{
    queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.myappname.filesystem.backgroundQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
});
return queue;
}
```

**Process Two:** Using local context for magical record

```
+ (void)getCurrentFolderFileForParentFolderID:(NSString *)parentFolderID sortBy:(NSString *)sortBy asending:(BOOL)asending withCompletionHandler:(void(^)(id response,NSError *error))completionHandler {
NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_context];
NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"parentfolderidlocal = %@", parentFolderID];
NSArray *folders = [Folders MR_findAllSortedBy:sortBy ascending:asending withPredicate:filter inContext:localContext];
NSArray *files = [Files MR_findAllSortedBy:sortBy ascending:asending withPredicate:filter inContext:localContext];
completionHandler(@{@"folders":folders,@"files":files},nil);
}
```

or

```
+ (void)getCurrentFolderFileForParentFolderID:(NSString *)parentFolderID sortBy:(NSString *)sortBy asending:(BOOL)asending withCompletionHandler:(void(^)(id response,NSError *error))completionHandler {
NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_context];
[localContext performBlock:^{
    NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"parentfolderidlocal = %@", parentFolderID];
    NSArray *folders = [Folders MR_findAllSortedBy:sortBy ascending:asending withPredicate:filter inContext:localContext];
    NSArray *files = [Files MR_findAllSortedBy:sortBy ascending:asending withPredicate:filter inContext:localContext];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        completionHandler(@{@"folders":folders,@"files":files},nil);
    });
}];
}
```

and calling it in dispatch queue as above or with out dispatch queue

In all the three cases for background thread I am having the following issue while using the data in a table view cell for row at index path:

**In normal instance it is working fine, I am getting the following**[image: Main Thread Result]

**But for background thread i am getting the object but no value(some times i am getting value though)**

[image: Back Ground Fetch response]

Please can any one help. I am stuck here. I need to use the dispatch queue here. I don't have that much good knowledge about background threading/dispatch. Please let me know, if I am doing anything wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

This question is not about MagicalRecord, it's about CoreData.
Two tips:
1. Save to persistent store before fetching from another thread;
2. Managed Object can only be used on the thread on which you fetch it.